# how to make a ecs web service task definition public on the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an ECS Cluster, an AWS ECS service with 1 ECS task definition that has a container that points to this simple [docker image](https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/nginx-hello) which is the Nginx hello image just for testing.

I now want to make this publicly available on the internet and I would like to use cloudfront.

How can I connect cloudfront to serve the content from the image?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to create an **Application Load Balancer** (ALB) with a *Listener* and a *Target Group*. Then you [register your ECS Service in the ALB Target Group](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-alb-auto-register/). That will expose the Nginx container to the internet through the ALB.

The reasons for this are:

- Containers in ECS Service can be terminated and restarted at which point they get a new IP address. The Service can register the newly started containers to ALB automatically.
- You can terminate SSL (HTTPS) on the ALB with a certificate issued by Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) without having to deal with SSL certificates on the container level.
- You can run your containers with *Private IP* addresses in a *Private subnet*. Only the ALB needs to be in a Public subnet.

Once you have **ALB + ECS** set up and working you can add **Cloud Front** to the mix. [*This blog post*](https://fastchicken.co.nz/2019/11/20/shut-the-back-door-locking-an-aws-alb-to-cloudfront/) has a couple of options on how to restrict access to ALB only from CloudFront, in particular I like *Option 2* - setting a **custom header** on the CF side and checking it in ALB.

Hope that helps :)